# How implement real time video encoding using Libde265 and Linux

Tags: linux, opencv, video-processing

I been reading a lot about H265 encoder  but I'm no really sure how to start a C or Python application to encode a video stream in real time using H.265 encoder from libde265, I all ready install the library and I guess I could use opencv to get the input video stream from a usb camera, do anyone has worked in this type of application ?

Comment: I'm working with OpenCV where I use a VideoCapture object to retrieve frames from an USB camera. For the encoding I'd use [x265](http://x265.org/), which seems to be well [documented](https://x265.readthedocs.org/en/default/api.html#introduction). I have not been able to find any docs regarding libde265

Answer (score 0):

If you are not particular about using libde265, which I am not aware of, please give a shot with gstreamer. gstreamer has lots of plugins and examples if you are doing some standard tasks like encoding on your stream. It also integrates well with native development.

I have worked on a project similar to yours, where we did H264 encoding and decoding along with few other things on a live camera feed.

Please find the video of a similar application here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcpkGDpfVU0

Just my two cents!!